# Better URL with mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla2.5, multiple-domains

Please, help me with this. I have my website in a directory /domains/mywebsite.com and I am using mod_rewrite to access the website, but the URL looks then like this:
        http://www.mywebsite.com/domains/mywebsite.com/something
So please how can I get off the /domains/mywebsite.com/ part from the URL?

Is there any other way how to make it possible except changing the public $live_site in the configuration.php (in Joomla)?

Comment: Can't you point the domain to the directory in the server config using cpanel or similar? Looks quite hackish to do this with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domains/mywebsite.com/$1
```

But I agree with Bakual's suggestion that this is not a great way to address the problem. Better to reconfigure your server so that it makes the /domains/mywebsite.com/ directory the public root directory for that domain.